# Is the 'Time' field provided by vbp or a DLL?

Tags: windows, dll, vb6

In this visual basic 6 app there is a field that repeats a lot, `Time` . For example:

```
hour = Hour(Time) *3600
```

That field isn't declared in the `(Declarations)` section, is that field incorporated by a dll or by vbp?

Comment: Time is a function defined in `DateTime` class of the VBA library.

Comment: i found it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the VB6 IDE *you can ask the IDE to tell you where something is defined*.

Right click on the variable, and select "Definition":

[image]

You can also press Shift-F2 to achieve the same result.

In the case of `Time`, doing this brings up the Object Browser window which shows the contents of all the library references in the project:

[image]

You can see that `Time` is a member of the `VBA.DateTime` class. The `VBA` library is a permanent part of any VB6 project. It is listed in Project > References:

[image]

You can see at the bottom of the window it is implemented in a particular 'system' DLL. Note that this reference cannot be removed, so `Time` and other items it contains are always available to any VB6 project.